# Writing numbers to cells as text

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to manipulate a dataset and ahve run into a problem; I need to write some values to cells but keep them as strings rather than numbers so later filters will work with other database data.

I was using Cell.Value = x which does the job but is there a way of getting it to write with a string?

I have a feeling this has a simple answer but my google-fu is weak.

Comment: You can set the number format on the cell to "text" before writing the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

1) Formatting the cell as text (available on a right click as 'Format Cells')

2) Clobbering the cell completely with `Cell.Value = "'" & CStr(x)`

I prefer (1) since it is separating data from presentation; always good programming practice.

Comment: Thanks, I am using your 2) currently. I had thought of 1) and if I was the only one using this sheet I would have used it but with others taking this in future/importing it to other workbooks I want it to be simple to port.

Comment: I'd say that (2) is only really permissible if the resulting values are never used in calculation. Otherwise you ought to format.

Comment: The only thing that happens with them after this step is that they are converted to text descriptions, the values written are just numerical codes rather than numerical information.